# Log file does not match the primary file. _log.ldf and .ldf files

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to store additional user information along with the membership providers in MVC4 in a single .mdf file. I have been working on a simple test Mvc4 application which uses Code first, and System.Web.Providers. 
The database has an initializer which drops and creates the database whenever the model changes. However whenever i do this i get an error stating:

One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup.
Cannot open database "MyNewTest" requested by the login. The login failed.
Log file ~\MvcTest.ldf' does not match the primary file.  It may be from a different database or the log may have been rebuilt previously.

If i look in the App_Data folder i now have two .ldf files. A MvcTest.ldf and a MvcTest_log.ldf. If i rename the MvcTest_log.ldf to the MvcTest.ldf file everything works again.

In my Web.Config file i have this

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcTest.mdf;Initial Catalog=MvcTest;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

My Context.cs file:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserInformation> UserInformation { get; set; }
}
```

My Initializer.cs file:

```
public class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>
{
    protected override void  Seed(Context context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }

}
```

And a Model file:

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public int UserInformationId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string callsign { get; set; }
}
```

I'm also wondering if I am going about this the wrong way. The reason I wanted the tables together is to enforce consistancy constraints.

Comment: Why are you using `AttachDbFileName`, `User Instance` and `MultipleActiveresultSets` - are you using these on purpose? Are you sure you know what they do and that you need them?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what they do and that i need them. I copied the connection string from this [guide](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)